# Website navigation on mobile

Tags: website-design, navigation, mobile-web

So I have a [lyrics website](https://www.bejebeje.com) and it is doing rather well in terms of organic traffic, so I thought I better make it as best as I can for my users.

On mobile devices, right now I am not hiding the navigation, and it just appears on top of the whole page, I find this rather cumbersome, cause the user has to scroll down in order to see artists.

[image]

What is the best approach to take here? Is it the hamburger menu where the navigation loads from left/right? Or are there better approaches?

Thanks

Comment: to @PixelSnader's point, is there a reason why your logo is taking up that much space? Why not have a header with the logo and menu items?

Comment: @Majo0od nope, no specific reason, when I first did this project, I just wanted something quick and dirty, but now that I have good traffic to the site, I want to optimise and make things as good as I can!

Comment: Makes sense. Good luck on the revamp!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem here is not that you have your menu options, but that you're using 60% of the screen just to show your logo.

Comment: Thanks @PixelSnader, so if I simply made my logo smaller, you think things will be well enough?

Answer (score 1):

Not only would I shrink your logo, but I would also move your search bar to a higher hierarchical position. I'm assuming your users are primarily using your page to search for something specific, not browse.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you re-size the logo so it doesn't take much space on the screen because user would have an overall layout. I would suggest to put the icon of search bar on the top of navigation. Here's a good explanation about the hamburger menu and also you can find some alternatives for your design:

[Hamburger menu alternatives for mobile navigation](https://medium.com/@kollinz/hamburger-menu-alternatives-for-mobile-navigation-a3a3beb555b8#.xrid3cnup)

I hope the article helps you to get an insight! Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Dealing with your website from Desktop is acceptable. But as others said for mobile usage, you have to re-size the logo as same as to put the search icon at the top of the navigation.

Mobile app design says if you have a limited number of sections in your app and users should be able to quickly switch between these sections, a **tabbed navigation** is a solution.
[image]

Tabs seem to be the simplest navigation pattern, however, you need to consider a few things when designing them such as you should have no more than five sections to display, one of the tabs should always be active and should visually be highlighted and the first tab has to be the home page or home screen and the order of the tabs should relate to their priority or logical order in the user flow.

Comment: Do you have examples of this being done on web pages?

Comment: Check - https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/04/showcase-of-well-designed-tabbed-navigation/

Comment: Sorry I meant, examples of where the page turns onto tabs only on mobile view? I don't think I've ever seen that